# Scanf does not read user input as expected

Tags: c, scanf

The program is not taking inputs as it should. When I input `t = 1` and `l = 4` the inner loop takes only two inputs instead of four.

```
int main() {
  int l, b, g, count, t, i;
  char s[10000];
  scanf("%d%d", &t, &l);

  while (t--) {
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
      scanf("%c", s[i]);
      if (i > 0)
        if (s[i] == s[i-1])
          count++;
    }
    printf("%d\n", count);
  }
  getch();      
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that when you enter a character for any `scanf`, you press the enter key. The input(if valid) is consumed by the `scanf` and the newline character(since you pressed the enter key) stays in the standard input stream(`stdin`). When `scanf`(with `%c`) is called the next time, it sees the `\n` character in the `stdin` and consumes it, and thus does not wait for further input.

To fix it, Change

```
scanf("%c",s[i]);
```

To

```
scanf(" %c",&s[i]);
```

The space before the `%c` instructs `scanf` to scan any number of whitespace characters including none, until the first non-whitespace character. Quoting the standard:

> **7.21.6.2 The fscanf function**
>
> [...]
>
> 5. A directive composed of white-space character(s) is executed by reading input up to the
>      first non-white-space character (which remains unread), or until no more characters can
>      be read. The directive never fails.

`scanf` with the `%c` format specifier expects a `char*` or in other words, the address of a `char`. You provide the argument `s[i]` which is of type `char`. This invokes Undefined behavior. `&` is the address of operator, and it, when used before `s[i]`, gives the address of `s[i]`, which is a `char*`.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main(){

    int  l,b,g,count,t,i;
    char s[10000];
    scanf("%d%d",&t,&l);
    getchar();
    while(t--){
         for(i=0;i<l;i++){
               scanf("%c",s[i]);
                      if(i>0)
                         if(s[i]==s[i-1])
                              count++;

               }
     printf("%d\n",count);

     }

     getch();      
    }
```

The two getchars are used to clear the '\n' that is there in the input buffer. The dummy getchars are just taking those extra '\n' and that will solve the problem.